# Codeigniter portnumber in url

Tags: codeigniter

im using code igniter current version .I moved all the files to the live server 
i access URl as http://xxx:8084/application/
My class does not seem to load ,$this also does not work
It stops executing before parent::controller ,i get call to a function model on non object

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to set the correct base URL in `application/config/config.php`. A generic solution that should work in most cases is:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

Comment: It stops executing before parent::controller ,i get call to a function model on non object